# What is the objective-c equivalent to Java's ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

I want to prepare a binary message in memory before sending it over the network.
What is the objective-c equivalent to Java's ByteArrayOutputStream?

I saw the somewhat complicated CFWriteStreamCreateWithAllocatedBuffers, and the simpler looking [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToMemory], however - I was not able to figure out how to use any of those.

A code sample that initializes an output stream, write some data into it and get the results bytes (in some form, NSData or char* or whatever) would really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation for NSOutputStream tells you what you need to do.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSOutputStream/outputStreamToMemory)

Comment: I tried something like the following, but it seems that propertyForKey returns nil data. any idea?
NSOutputStream *out = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToMemory]; [self writeString:out str:self.m_sessionId];NSData *data = [out propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];

Comment: You didn't do everything the documentation told you to do. You need to open the stream before you write to it and close it when you're done with it.